# how to edit value of 3 labels after clicking on a href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, label

I want to make three different labels editable when I click on a single href
I have:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">PLZ:</td>

    <td>
        <label for="name" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">
                <label style="color: #662819;" id="plz"></label>
                <i class="icon-star"></i>
            </p>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="edit-input" />

        <div class="controls">
            <a class="edit" href="#">Daten sichern</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

changing this one label with:

**CSS:**

```
.edit-input {
    display:none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('a.edit').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
        var lbl = dad.find('label');
        lbl.hide();
        dad.find('input[type="text"]').val(lbl.text()).show().focus();
    });

    $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('label').text(this.value).show();
    });
});
```

how to do it for 2 or more labels??? like for follow ones...:

```
<tr>
      <td align="left">Strasse:</td>
      <td>
        <label for="name" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">
                <label style="color: #662819;" id="street"></label>
                <i class="icon-star"></i>
            </p>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="edit-input" />  
      </td>
</tr>
```

and so on...

Comment: how to do it with my code? help me please!

Comment: you want to make three different labels editable when you click on a single href?

Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @crenckly YES! i want do excatly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make different labels editable at the same time, when you click a single link, you can use JQuery's each function, as shown in the following code:

```
$('a.edit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Search for .control-label items
    $('label.control-label').each(function(key,item){
        var label = $(item);          
        label.hide();
        label.siblings('input.edit-input').val(label.text()).show().focus();
    });

});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey, your method making just a last label of 3 editable... first 2 are ignored.

Comment: All your labels have `class='control-label'`?

Comment: you have a JSFiddle or something to look the code. The code of the answer may work :S